# Handling signin flow in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, last.fm

I'm trying to implement Last.fm signin in React. After the user logins to Last.fm, they are redirected to

```
http://localhost:3000/loginlanding/?token=${token id goes here}
```

How do I capture the url using React Router?
So far, I have tried all these:

```
path="/loginlanding/?token:id"
path="/loginlanding/:id"
path="/loginlanding/?:id"
```

None of these seem to work.
Basically, I need to capture the access token and store it in global state.

Comment: try ```to='/loginlanding?token=${ token_id }'```

Comment: The page is redirected by last.fm not by the React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**specify route**

```
<Route path="/loginlanding/:token_id" component={LoginLanding} />
```

**pass token**

```
<Link to=`/loginlanding/${token_id}` />
```

**get token**

```
this.props.match.params.token_id
```

Comment: Maybe, my post was confusing. So, after the user logins to Last.fm, it redirects to page to  ` http://localhost:3000/loginlanding/?token=1zdTVPF0dmgFsB2PrPsUjdPC9vA3XILP`

Comment: I'm not able to capture that particular url format. "/loginlanding/:token_id" does not work.

Comment: please be more clear, is it => you have a url, and you want to extract some information from that url?

Answer (score 0):

**you can store your token in the localstorage and access it from there whenever needed.
Or if the token is available in the parent component you can access it as a prop like this.
**

```
    {match:{params:{id}}} //<<<< This can be accessed in the react-router
```